# Hashtag causes page to scroll to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, hashtag

I have the following script included in my fancybox script:

```
beforeShow: function () {
    var id = this.element.attr("id")
    if (id) {
        window.location.hash = id;
    }
},                  
beforeClose: function() {
    window.location.hash = "";
}
```

Basically if I open an image with fancybox, the url will change to /#image and when the fancybox window is closed, the url changes to /#. But when this happens, the page scrolls back to the top. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645202/can-i-update-window-location-hash-without-having-the-web-page-scroll

Answer (score 1):

You may store previous value:

```
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
// change hash to #
$(window).scrollTop(scroll);
```

Comment: Thank you. However, is it possible for it not to scroll to the beginning of the image and instead load the previous scroll location?