# PHP save a page then redirect to previous page(ajax)

Tags: php, ajax, http-referer

I would like to ask for how to redirect to previous page (ajax paging).

Example,
Let's say currently I am in page 5, then I click on one record, after I edit it, I would like to go back to that page 5 not page 1.

The problem is my paging is using ajax,

http://domain/photo/#5

I try to use $_SERVER[http_referer], but I only get http://domain/photo , I not able to get # and the value.

What is the best way to redirect back to the previous paging. My last choice is using $_SESSION. Hope I can get better answer here.

Thx.

Comment: Anchors are interpreted by the browser, thus I don't think they're sent to the PHP engine at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Lauri says, you need to manage this at the client-side using Javascript. Basically you need to implement some sort of client-side browser history. Just look at how Facebook loads in photos, but still lets you use the back button.

There are various libraries available to help you:

[JS History Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657310/experiences-with-javascript-history-frameworks)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think Ajax need to use back JS to do back the mechanism. Thank you guys!